# Относительные ссылки и использование include

Tags: php, ссылки, include, навигация

*Всем доброго времени суток.*

Шапка сайта, навигация и подвал лежат в отдельных php-файлах внутри папки pages (*mysite.ru/pages/header.php* и т.д.). В файле навигации прописаны относительные ссылки к страничкам. Если использую index.php (он расположен в корне сайта, при помощи `include "file_name.php";` подключаю нужные файлы), то всё работает правильно. Если обращаюсь к этим файлам из подпапки, то уже ссылки идут не на поиск файлов в корне, а в этой самой подпапке (например: `mysite.ru/folder/index.php` вместо `mysite.ru/index.php`). Как исправить этот момент в навигации?

**P.S.** Если моё решение (в корне лежит только index.php, в папке pages шапка, навигация и подвал, а в остальных папках файлы по разделам сайта) считаете глупым/неверным, то подскажите, как лучше сделать.

Comment: Используйте `DOCUMENT_ROOT` для основы путей к файлам

Comment: @vp_arth, не выходит. ссылается на какую-то дребедень. Может, на физическое расположение файла, чёрт его знает. Вот это перед наименованием сайта выводит: `/var/www/domains/t/te/tes/`

Comment: Ну тут конечно относительные ссылки - вообще не вариант. Лично я просто задаю константу пути рута, аля `define('ROOT_PATH','app/files/')` и от нее пляшу.

Answer (score 2):

к инклюдам этот вопрос не имеет никакого отношения.

> В файле навигации прописаны относительные ссылки к страничкам.

Это неправильно. Ссылки должны быть [абсолютные](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths):

> для того, чтобы любая ссылка гарантированно работала, независимо от того, из какого места сайта она вызывается, она должна быть **абсолютной**.
>
> Если у вас на сайте есть, допустим, два раздела:
>   http://www.example.com/about/info.php
>   и
>   http://www.example.com/job/vacancy.php
>
> то, если в файле info.php сделать ссылку просто на vacancy.php, то браузер ее не найдет - он будет искать адрес http://www.example.com/about/vacancy.php, достраивая путь от текущего каталога.
>
> Поэтому надо писать полный путь от корня сайта - /job/vacancy.php
>   Всё это касается, естественно, не только тегов  но и  и любых других, где используются ссылки на другие файлы.
>
> Ссылки на локальные адреса следует писать без указания протокола и домена - только путь от корня сайта - /job/vacancy.php. Ссылки же на другие сайты следует писать полностью - http://www.example.com/job/vacancy.php.

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, краткую выдержку из статьи, на которую ссылаетесь. Однажды она исчезнет, а ответ останется.

Comment: @Ипатьев, это всё интересно, но при попытке узнать у переменной `$_SERVER` её `'SERVER_NAME'` мне, как бы помягче выразиться, всё равно не дают ссылку на "корень" сайта. Может, я что-то не то делаю. Уже и не знаю даже.

Comment: НЕ НУЖНА ТЕБЕ НИКАКАЯ 'SERVER_NAME'! Тут русским по желтому написано, **Ссылки на локальные адреса следует писать без указания протокола и домена - только путь от корня сайта - /job/vacancy.php.** Ссылку на корень сайта не нужно "узнавать". Она всегда одна и та же - "/". От нее должны начинаться все ссылки на сайте

Answer (score 1):

чтоб вернуться на уровень выше пишите `../`. Если нужно с папки обратится в соседнюю папку тогда сначала выходим с текущей папки и заходим в нужную:

`../folder/file.php`

Возможно вам лучше будет использовать абсолютный путь..

`"http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.. и сюда уже прописывать в ссылках остальной путь. Н-д :

`"http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']  . "/folder/header.php"`.

Тогда независимо откуда вы обращаетесь к файлу ссылка не меняется - не взникает путаницы

Comment: `"/var/www/domains/t/te/tes/"` - сначала пишет это, а только потом название сайта и ссылку на страницу. Разумеется, сразу выпадает 404-я.

Comment: Поправил.. не ту переменную использовал.. она была для доступа к файлам внутри кода

Comment: Не надо пытаться исправлять заведомо кривой ответ. Если знаний нет, то никакие исправления не помогут

Answer (score -1):

Лучше использовать структуру [MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), может будет не настолько удобно как в твоем случае но правильнее и не будет путаницы

Comment: Полагаю, вы имели в виду `Front Controller`

Comment: @vp_arth как вариант =)

Comment: А если у него там лендинг на 2 страницы без бекэнд логики? Больше смахивает на комментарий, нежели на ответ.

Comment: @SLy_huh Он сам в своем вопросе попросил посоветовать, а если у него лендинг тогда зачем все так усложнять? Что мешает выводить меню сразу в тексте страницы, не думаю что на лендинге оно должно как-то динамически генерироваться.

Comment: Мне просто удобней разделить на разделы страницу. Не очень нравится, когда одно и то же в каждой странице копипастить. Лучше дать ссылку на одинаковый объект/вьюшку/... Страниц будет немного. Не больше десятка, наверное.

Comment: Ну для советов в одну строку логичнее использовать `комментарии`. Ваш ответ никак не коррелирует с самим вопросом. Разделение страницы на блоки не всегда предполагает MVC.

Comment: @SLy_huh Я думал Вы учли тот факт что моя репутация на данном ресурсе менее 50-ти баллов и я не могу комментировать пост ТС, а могу лишь отвечать на него.

Comment: Я думал, Вы учли тот факт, что это намеренное решение? Если нет подходящего ответа, то не следует размещать свой комментарий в качестве ответа.

Comment: @SLy_huh человек в своем сообщении попросил совета, изначально его путь выполнения данной задачи был не совсем правильным, я и посоветовал более правильное решения поставленной задачи.